# Mocking LocalDate.now() but when using plusDays it returns null?

Tags: java, java-time

In my code I need to use LocalDate.now(), then I work out an estimated date from today by using the plusDays(num).

In my unit test, when I mock the static .now() method, when it calls the plusDays() method the output is null.

Any Ideas?

**Code**

```
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
int estimatedDays = fullPeriod - countSoFar;
LocalDate estimatedDate  = today.plusDays(estimatedDays);
```

**Test**

```
try(MockedStatic<LocalDate> mockedLocalDate = Mockito.mockStatic(LocalDate.class)) {
            mockedLocalDate.when(LocalDate::now).thenReturn(startDate);

            String actual = generator.generateCsv("text", "text", startDate, endDate);

            String expected = "Some text containing {Estimated Date}";
            assertEquals(expected, actual);
}
```

Edit:
[image]

When I mock the LocalDate it looks normal in the call to LocalDate.now() but when it goes into the plusDay() method it returns null

Inside the Math function r is not null at this point but as soon as it comes out this method the resultant variable is?

[image]

Comment: What does the debugger say?

Comment: which "method output is null"? do we have the code for it? what is `startDate` in given test code?  ideally the question would include a [mre]

Comment: @user16320675 startDate and endDate are parameters passed into the code from an endpoint. Its a springboot project.

estimatedDate is null when today.plusDays(estimatedDays); returns a value.

When I debugged it, it looks like in the bit of the LocalDate class plusDays 

   
        long mjDay = Math.addExact(toEpochDay(), daysToAdd);
        return LocalDate.ofEpochDay(mjDay);

toEpochDay() is null because its a mocked instance

Comment: @Kayaman I've added an edit to show what is happening in the LocalDate plusDays method

Comment: You seem to be misinterpreting the debugger. It doesn't return null, it's just referring to the unintialized `mjDays` variable because you've stopped execution before it gets initialized. I don't know what your "returns null" or "outputs null" means. If you get a `NullPointerException`, that would be a certain indication of a `null` somewhere.

Comment: Just added another screenshot, I think it could be how it is saving it in memory? @Kayaman slot 4 has the variable but slot 3 doesnt and its using that?

Comment: Don't start guessing. The variable `mjDay` is in `slot_3` and it's completely irrelevant to anything. You haven't shown an error message.

Comment: Its not an error I said that at the start? I said that the resultant variable estimatedDate is coming back as null. When I debug the code it all looks fine until it comes out the Math.exact() method which returns null. I dont really know what your issue is? @Kayaman

Comment: Well, for one `Math.addExact()` returns a `long` which can't be `null`. Second, you can't read the debugger output so you think things are happening which aren't. You're looking at an uninitialized variable, which shows as `null` (even though it's a `long`), and that's what you were concerned about? Does your test pass? Try stepping with the debugger to the actual return statement, and you'll see the initialized value.

Comment: See the first screen shot mJDay is null, I dont really understand the attack here. Stackoverflow is for helping not attacking other people who want help. No the test doesnt pass or else I wouldnt be on here asking a question? @Kayaman

Comment: Don't consider it a personal attack, it's more of a fight against ignorance. Like I said, `mjDay` isn't `null` since primitives can't hold null values. The debugger shows it as null because it's uninitialized. If the tests don't pass, what's the error message? Are you assuming that this is the only reason the tests can't pass?

Comment: Instead of wasting your time on static mocking and debugging the Java API, use best practices and inject a Clock

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## `java.time.Clock`

Instead of mocking a static method (which is never a good idea really IMO) you can use the [Clock feature offered by the java.time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#now-java.time.Clock-) itself. You can pass an instance of java.time.Clock, a [fixed](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Clock.html#fixed-java.time.Instant-java.time.ZoneId-) clock for example.

From the [`Clock`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Clock.html) JavaDoc:

> Best practice for applications is to pass a Clock into any method that requires the current instant. A dependency injection framework is one way to achieve this:

```
public class MyBean {
 private Clock clock;  // dependency inject
 ...
 public void process(LocalDate eventDate) {
   if (eventDate.isBefore(LocalDate.now(clock)) {
     ...
   }
 }
}
```

> This approach allows an alternate clock, such as fixed or offset to be used during testing.

Comment: That is actually the correct solution. I regularly inject the clock in order to be able to fix it for tests.